# How to identify a node with its XML value in XPath?

Tags: html, r, xml, xpath, web-scraping

I use R to scrape a web site, and when parsing the HTML code, I have this code below:

```
    <div class="line">
        <h2 class="clearfix">
            <span class="property">Number<div>number extra</div></span>
            <span class="value">3</span>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <h2 class="clearfix">
            <span class="property">Surface</span>
            <span class="value">72</span>
        </h2>
    </div>
```

Now I would like to get some values in this code.

- How to identify the span with the xml value "Number". and get the node, in order to extract "number extra"?
  I know how to use xpathApply to identify nodes in order to get the xmlValue or some attributes (like `href` with `xmlGetAttr`). But I don't know how to identify a node with knowing its xmlvalue.

  ```
    xpathApply(page, '//span[@class="property"]',xmlValue)
  ```
- If I want to get the "value" 72 for the property class "Surface", what is the most efficient way?

Here's I started to do:
First, I extract all "property":

```
xpathApply(page, '//span[@class="property"]',xmlValue)
```

Then I extract all "value":

```
xpathApply(page, '//span[@class="value"]',xmlValue)
```

Then I build a list or a matrix, so that I can identify the value of "Surface", which is 72. But the problem is that sometimes, a span with `class="property"` can not have a span with class="value" that just follows in a `h2`. So I can not build a proper list.

Could this be the most efficient way? Identify the span with `class="property"`, then identify the `h2` that contains this `span`, then identify the `span` with `class="value"`?

Comment: thank you @kjhughes for editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your HTML made to be well-formed by adding a single root element,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<r> 
  <div class="line"> 
    <h2 class="clearfix"> 
      <span class="property">Number
        <div>number extra</div>
      </span>  
      <span class="value">3</span> 
    </h2> 
  </div>  
  <div class="line"> 
    <h2 class="clearfix"> 
      <span class="property">Surface</span>  
      <span class="value">72</span> 
    </h2> 
  </div> 
</r>
```

---

**(A)** This XPath expression,

```
//span[@class='property' and starts-with(., 'Number')]/div/text()
```

will return

```
number extra
```

as requested.

---

**(B)** This XPath expression,

```
//h2[span[@class='property' and . = 'Surface']]/span[@class='value']/text()
```

will return

```
72
```

as requested.

Comment: Thank you very much @kjhughes

Answer (score 1):

XPath can evaluate the contents of a tag using its own function `text()`. Using `rvest` for simplicity:

```
library(rvest)

html <- '<div class="line">
        <h2 class="clearfix">
<span class="property">Number<div>number extra</div></span>
<span class="value">3</span>
</h2>
</div>
<div class="line">
<h2 class="clearfix">
<span class="property">Surface</span>
<span class="value">72</span>
</h2>
</div>' 

html %>% read_html() %>%    # read html
    html_nodes(xpath = '//span[text()="Number"]/*') %>%    # select node
    html_text()    # get text contents of node
# [1] "number extra"
```

XPath also has [selectors to follow family axes](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp), in this case `following::`:

```
html %>% read_html() %>%    # read html
    html_nodes(xpath = '//span[text()="Surface"]/following::*') %>%    # select node
    html_text()    # get text contents of node
# [1] "72"
```

Comment: Thank you very much @alistaire

Comment: thank you again for your answer. I noticed that `following::` works fine when there is no `span` after. What should you to get `3` in my example? which is the `value` of Number. Thank you